# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable en python

Tags: python

La idea es ingresar 2 números y ver cuál es el mayor

```py
    num1=int(input('Ingrese 1 número entero: '))
    num2=int(input('Ingrese otro número entero: '))
    
    if num1>num2:
        print((num1)(' es mayor que ')(num2))
    else:
        print((num2) (' es mayor que ')(num1))
```

pero lanza salta este error:

[image: error]

Como puedo hacer para que me lance ese *print* con los números que se deben ingresar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la manera que imprimes las variables entre paréntesis. Debes concatenar las variables en el print mediante comas de la siguiente manera:

```
num1=int(input('Ingrese 1 número entero: '))
num2=int(input('Ingrese otro número entero: '))

if num1>num2:
    print(num1,(' es mayor que '),num2)
else:
    print(num2,(' es mayor que '),num1)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás impriendo mal el resultado. Abajo te dejo tres formas de hacerlo:

```
num1=int(input('Ingrese 1 número entero: '))
num2=int(input('Ingrese otro número entero: '))

# Forma Nº1   
if num1>num2:
    print('{} es mayor que {}'.format(num1, num2))
else:
    print('{} es mayor que {}'.format(num2, num1))

# Forma Nº2   
if num1>num2:
    print(num1, 'es mayor que' ,num2)
else:
    print(num2, 'es mayor que' ,num1)

# Forma Nº3   
if num1>num2:
    print(f'{num1} es mayor que {num2}')
else:
    print(f'{num2} es mayor que {num1}')
```

Saludos,